# Initialize tinyMCE before textarea visible

Tags: tinymce

how can I init tinyMCE before the element it is to apply to is not yet visible?

So yeah, this doesn't work in my case.

```
tinyMCE.init({
```

Comment: not yet visible or not yet present on page?

Comment: Not yet visible, but both if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are dynamically adding the textarea triggered from some action, then you can use the TinyMCE command "mceAddControl" to add TinyMCE to the page.

For example, if the textarea ID is "myText" then you add the editor control with

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', true,"myText");
```

Of course, you need to setup the editor settings prior to adding the control. This is done by setting the setting attribute of the control. For example

```
tinyMCE.settings = {
                     theme: 'advanced', 
                     ....
                   };
```

Comment: Ok. I will try this out thanks. So will it initialize immediately as I exec. this function? As that is the reason why I need another method other than the official one to starting tinyMCE.

Comment: If by "initialize immediately" you mean that it instantiates TinyMCE and replaces the TextArea then yes.

Comment: Great. Thanks! I will use your code when I get to that problem again :)

Comment: When i am using v-if in vue.js, within this v-if div i cannot initialize tinymce